# How to concat a nested flux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How to concatenate two flux with a nested one? Why this code execution never ends?

```
@Test
fun `concatenating two flux`() {

    val names = listOf("israel", "israel")

    val a = Flux.just("a", "v")
            .flatMap { it.toUpperCase().toMono() }
            .concatWith { names.joinToString(" ").toMono() }

    StepVerifier.create(a).expectNext("A", "V", "israel israel").verifyComplete()
}
```

when I have the flux with separated variable, the execution runs as expected

```
@Test
fun `concatenating two flux`() {

    val names = listOf("israel", "israel")

    val b = names.joinToString(" ").toMono()

    val a = Flux.just("a", "v")
            .flatMap { it.toUpperCase().toMono() }

    val c = a.concatWith(b)

    StepVerifier.create(c.log()).expectNext("A", "V", "israel israel").verifyComplete()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `()` intead of `{}` in `concatWith()`

```
// RIGHT!

    Flux.just("a", "v")
                    .flatMap { it.toUpperCase().toMono() }
                    .concatWith ( names.joinToString(" ").toMono() )

// WRONG!

    Flux.just("a", "v")
                    .flatMap { it.toUpperCase().toMono() }
                    .concatWith { names.joinToString(" ").toMono() }
```

Most of Rx2 methods do accept actual lambdas, some of methods take `Callable<ObservableSource<T>>` instead of `ObservableSource`, others take `Function<T, ObservableSource<R>>`.

`Observable.defer { Observable.just(1) }` — this will work fine.

Or 
`observable.flatMap { Observable.just(1) }` — will work as expected too (if you’re ignoring incoming param purposely).

And the third one is the fact that we got used to Rx1 which always took `Observable` in its `andThen()` method, which couldn’t be represented as lambda , which is why we need to use `()` instead of `{}`